# Are there any restrictions on the usage of the て-form as a continuation?

Tags: grammar, て-form

How freely can sentences be combined with the て-form? Are there any cases where it cannot be done?

Comment: This question is too broad. You can't just join any two sentences with the てーform. Do you have a particular case in mind where you don't understand why the てーform does not work or you think it should work but you are told it does not?

Comment: @Tim Ah, sorry about that. I guess there's no short answer, then. Unfortunately, I don't have a proper example of the types you mentioned. More specifically, I was thinking about whether you can mix such things as tense, aspect, or subject when you combine sentences. And if controllability affects anything.

Comment: It is a good topic but at the moment you stand to get somebody just reproducing their text book.